# Did the Sturmabteilung uniform look ridiculous in terms of German fashion in the 1920s?

Tags: germany, uniform, fashion, fascism

Ridicule is a common method of social dismissal. The Sturmabteilung (SA) were a German fascist militia in the 1920s, 1930s and 1940s. [Their most basic uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniforms_and_insignia_of_the_Sturmabteilung) was described as a yellow brown Kaiserreich desert uniform. Unlike the Schutzstaffel the SA did not benefit from a fashion designed uniform.

[image: Real SA uniform, src https://www.dhm.de/lemo/bestand/objekt/uniform-der-sa-um-1930.html]

Were the SA subject to ridicule in Germany?
In terms of the relevant fashion cultures of Germany, did they look ridiculous?

Comment: Into the early 1930s the SA were faced by social democrat and communist organised militia who lacked uniform. Citing their growing power in the early 1930s for 20s fashion isn’t a complete argument. We view them through Riefenstahls lens in what amounted to a tribute to the SA after they had been very publicly neutered. I’m asking for an “as it was” reading, not an after Leni reading.

Comment: My parents once told me that Mussolini's thugs would force feed castor oil to people they scuffled with on the streets.  Being a powerful laxative, you can imagine what that would do to make someone look foolish, an hour or two later.  Wonder if there's any truth to that or if it was an urban legend of the time?

Comment: The SA were definitely subject to abuse and ridicule by communists and leftists, focusing on various aspects which probably included their uniform (there are certainly caricatures of German uniforms of the period by the likes of George Grosz, although some uniforms were even more ridiculous, such as the WW1-era cavalry's legendarily tight trousers). I'll see if I can find something relating to the SA.

Comment: Apart from again a very first comment being a factually wrong answer-in-comment (why don't we delete them, again, enlighten me please, tired of denied flags while those are clearly against policy…?); @SamuelRussell: "Lacked uniform"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichsbanner_Schwarz-Rot-Gold Please clarify *how* you'd like to measure this. 'Uniforms' were just a big thing then in general, opponents always tending to 'not like' the others, and fashion being a taste thing. I can easily cite subjective judgements pro&contra "nice boots they had and the puffy trousers were tres chic".

Comment: Sturmabteilung please.

Comment: @langlangc thank you for the correction regarding the reichsbanners uniform. The issue I think I outline by comparing the apparently dorky SA uniform and the apparently “cool” SS uniform is beyond merely ideological ridicule into general fashion. Punk in 77 was crud. In 1997 crud was fashion. In Australia the police and army look “cool,” and the navy look like “dorks” because you don’t need sea themed camo for every day wear.

Comment: SA were not fascist militia, there are significant ideological differences. Uniforms were German colonial uniforms of the era, thus the color. SA bought them because they were cheap surplus. Anyone ridiculing them would in fact ridicule German Army, so only hardcore leftist would do so .

Comment: @rs.29 As source for this information would be useful.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Simple internet search goes a long way ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturmabteilung

Comment: @rs.29 I was looking at: [Uniforms and insignia of the Sturmabteilung - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniforms_and_insignia_of_the_Sturmabteilung), which doesn't meation where the color comes from, but states: **The most common of these were World War I uniforms with full medals. Also common were uniforms of the Freikorps as well as uniforms of veteran groups such as Der Stahlhelm.** which explains more where the (riding) pants and boots come from.  Images in [Schutztruppe – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutztruppe) show a different style.

Comment: @rs.29 So saying that it originated from army surplus, which the color from East Africa Colonial uniforms might be a more generaly valid conclusion.

Comment: @rs.29 Since East Africa had been cut off from Germany in 1914, it is unlikely that there was a surplus at all in 1921. The strait pants if the colonal uniform doesn't match the bulging ones of the SA. Other than the color, the *Toland, John (1976). Adolf Hitler* quote ('having originally been ordered during the war for colonial troops posted to Germany's former African colonies.') seems doubtful. Most of those uniforms were also grey, only a small portion brown.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Quite the opposite, because East Africa was cut off, troops being there could not be supplied from wartime depots which were in Germany. Also SA probably ordered anything that was cheap, and cavalry trousers (being unused in trench WW1) were also included.

Comment: @rs.29 And you really believe that the material would not be used for the over 13 Million soldiers that were enlisted in Germany between 1914 and 1918? Most of the wool needed was imported from the US (and thus blockaded). An unrealistic assumption. LangLangC unsourced quote ('newly designed light beige-brown shirts') is possible, but the quote in the Wiki article that you are using is not.

Comment: @MarkJohnson What to do with already made clothes, most likely before the war? Completely unsuitable for European battlefield, and with notorious German bureaucracy expecting them be issued to colonial troops after German victory. It seems quite possible they were stashed somewhere until the end of the war, and then sold at discount as everything was crumbling around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is currently still unclear to which extent and from what angle "any ridicule" might have come. Of course there was some ridicule towards those uniformed men, and of course that ridicule mainly came from political opponents.

Uniforms of all kinds were still in much respect and fashion in Germany. Be it old Kaisers Rock (Prussian uniform, including equivalents from other states), police, firefighters, then later communist fighter brigades or mainly [Social-Democrat fighting brigades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichsbanner_Schwarz-Rot-Gold).

Unless that angle is better focused and explained, this answer will be restricted to address a common misconception about 'the uniform' as apparently informing the nature of the question — and most certainly a lot of comments.

The SA was called at a time *Braunhemden* (brown *shirts*).

That is significant, as the history of the organisation has to be looked at in the different phases.

First phase: 'a Jew' Emile Maurice creates the sports division of the party, which attracts ruffians, mostly from the Kaiser's military and later Freikorps. They wear their old uniforms, pretty much rag-tag style. When they try to appear 'uniform' in public the colour grey dominates *for windbreakers* and the only real identification signifier is the armband. The name *Sturmabteilung* was only chosen in 1921. And up to that point, no SA man wore brown shirts for party affiliation (ie: in private they might still have liked to don one).

[image] [image]

An independent Freikorps Roßbach comes into view. [He is a right-wing extremist,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Ro%C3%9Fbach) has his own Freikorps, and two coincidences on his side. He organises a holiday bike ride for his comrades to East Prussia in 1921, now under a more inoccuous name ("Verein für Wanderfahrten"). To appear in uniform style, he choses for his outfit a small surplus under his control from decommissioned colonial stocks. Out of those the intended but never delivered newly designed light beige-brown shirts for the East-Africa Schutztruppe under Paul Emil von Lettow-Vorbeck fitted his bill. These were and are nicknamed *Lettowhemden* ('Lettow's shirts') after the officer whose troops were the intended receivers of the uniforms including the shirts. Those were never made again in that exact style, stocks ran out fast but the impression of uniform earth-like colours for earth and ground (Blut & Boden) loving right-wingers catches on. Mainly since grey stood for the old field army, red the communists and firm black by then in use by Italian fascists.

The name *Lettowhemd* is still retained, informally, and giving rise to much of the misconceptions on display here. But the colour, cut, material etc differ substantially from the later *'Hitlerhemd'* (as so called by Roßbach). The later and latter is much darker brown, less like a fit for an African bush soldier, more like one for an Alpine huntsman.

During the prohibition of the NSDAP phase, such outfits were not opportune in general, and until then the spread from Bavaria into North Germany wasn't as big as later.

The basic 'uniform' style for the SA was then sought to be standardised in 1926 through the party, while wearing such a brown shirt was already made compulsory since 1925. They ordered large contingents of the same basic style for the masses, not least for brand recognition and corporate identity reasons but also to make that more affordable for the lower strata of society filling their ranks.

That went in parallel with really well-off members getting their shirts tailor-made while right up into the 1930s really poor members still making their own shirts for simple price reasons. While buying in bulk the centralised Sportversand made quite an income from its margins. This variation in styles is seen in trousers as well, and it becomes evident when looking at authentic pictures from that time.

This picture showing the important members [Heines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Heines) and Röhm in 1933 shows some variations:

[image]

It shows Heines, the SA hothead who in his own heyday introduced a basic brown shirt, first as a 'real uniform' into the youth organisation Schilljugend, after Roßbach's idea and following partly the style of the previous colonial gear.

So, for well into the 1930s, it is hardly '*the* uniform' of the SA to speak of. Official regulations standardising every last detail of that later uniforms that we might associate readily with such advertising masterminds like the nazis can not be used as a template to look for validation during the earlier phases. The most basic derision towards the SA's outward appearance was more to the *lack* of uniform (and the truncheon-swinging loudmouth behaviour of course) because they were right-wing but often poor, an unnatural combination.

Sources:

— [Freikorps Roßbach, 1919-1923](https://www.historisches-lexikon-bayerns.de/Lexikon/Freikorps_Ro%C3%9Fbach,_1919-1923)
— [Sturmabteilung (SA), 1921-1923/1925-1945](https://www.historisches-lexikon-bayerns.de/Lexikon/Sturmabteilung_(SA),_1921-1923/1925-1945)
— For the Roßbach/Lettowhemd angle: *not* [WP: SA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturmabteilung#cite_note-HeinzH%C3%B6hne/27-12), but
— Gerhard Rossbach: "Mein Weg durch die Zeit. Erinnerungen und Bekenntnisse", 1950. (Chapter: "Meine Beziehung zu den Braunhemden" describing the original Africa-destined shirt he bought up in detail, quoted in a short but easier to access manner [here](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110928648).)
— Freiherr von Eelking: "Die Uniformen der Braunhemden", Zentralverlag der NSDAP Franz Eher Nachf: München, 1934. ([archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Eelking-Freiherr-von-Die-Uniformen); bad barely readble scan but correctly shows some developments roughly correct for the timeline in pictures, of course much oversimplified as well and never mentioning then already disgraced persons…)
— Daniel Siemens: "Sturmabteilung. Die Geschichte der SA", Siedler: Berlin, 2019.

Since the fashion topic 'uniform' was of course generally rejected wholesale by pacifist or 'strictly civilian' circles after the Great War, it retained much appeal in German everyday life. In fact, I'd argue that when the SA finally gained some more ground during the later 1920s, while they adopted more stringent uniform-like appearances, they were more of a trendsetter in that regard for the opposing sides, who in part also wanted to appear 'en bloc' on the streets (and according to the SA source Eelking did so before the SA arrived at the brown basics).

Comment: Which source makes this statement: 'light brown shirts for the East-Africa Schutztruppe'? After 6 years of blockade and war it is surprising that the material would not have be reused.

Comment: @MarkJohnson A valid concern. It's directly from Rossbach.  Not all stocks were completely used up, the military holding on to theirs as fast & tight as it gets, and when Roßbach came along _they did_ let that one enter general circulation (re-use), plus it was a relatively small stock (compared to Prussian army uniforms).

Comment: The statement made in [Sturmabteilung - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturmabteilung), I believe, needs replacement. This quote would be a good candidate (and more plausible), but a source would be needed. Did it state the initial amount?

Comment: I have not yet commented but thank you.  For the UK influenced "honours" system of history, this is the summary of the honours thesis answer: the introduction to the "lower" PhD essay.  I want to congratulate this answer separate to the upvoting and acceptance.  THIS IS WHAT HIST.SE OUGHT TO ASPIRE. except with my ignorance of question.  regarding answers this is to what we should aspire.

Comment: @SamuelRussell Based on discussions in [history.meta.stackexchange](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4212/38607), the writing style of this author has been criticized in the past, which this answer also contains some aspects of.

Comment: @SamuelRussell The quoted publication: **Die Uniformen der Braunhemden** (Copy deadline 1934-03-01, just short of 3 months before Heines and Röhns arrested and executed), meantions only two peaple: '*The brown color, which indicates the closeness to nature, is Adolf Hitler's favorite color, as was Bismarck's.*' The authors conclusion about this publication includes: `never mentioning then already disgraced persons`, which I assume `Heines, the SA hothead` is meant. Such a style should not be considered something to aspire to.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace *Lettowhemd* is the term often found in the German text and was described in this answer as: 'designed **light beige-brown shirts** for the East-Africa Schutztruppe under Paul Emil von **Lettow**-Vorbeck'

Comment: This kind of constantly harassing criticism about 'style' is inspiredly incomprehensible. SA leadership fell from grace in January 34; book used was finalised March 34. That Heines & Röhm were killed in July 34 & are *not* mentioned in it is – despite being providers of important stepping stones – exactly the point to recognise: all things done were then described as the result of one man's actions. Are my detractors interpreting non-existent things into a text or just do not understand it? On this level, such 'criticism' cannot be addressed in any meaningful way.

Comment: @LаngLаngС Your statement about *Die Uniformen der Braunhemden* is purely speculative and not based on facts. The rif between Hitler and Röhm started after the 28th of February andcame to head in June. [Growing pressure against the SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Long_Knives#Growing_pressure_against_the_SA). Just because the book only meantions 2 peaple (Hitler and Bismarck) cannot lead to your conclusion that `never mentioning then already disgraced persons` was done with deliberate intension. Pure, unimaginative, speculation on your part.

Comment: Ah. So it is only your interpretation after all. My mere *description* of 2 important figures being *indeed not mentioned* in that book is evidently correct. Any "intensions" you read into that may or may not have been present for this fact. There is coincidence & caveat lector, but not that logical connector you seem to imagine here (hint something like because/therefore or sth like that). That *you conclude* this as the main *reason* is irrelevant. I highlight the fact that for a valuable historical description and explanation, the book lacks both names, but would benefit from having them.

Comment: @LаngLаngС If you have problems with this, feel free to complain at meta (as you did about your deleted answer: [Undeleting a net-score unpopular but well written, amply referenced, upvoted and accepted quality answer? - History Meta Stack Exchange](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/undeleting-a-net-score-unpopular-but-well-written-amply-referenced-upvoted-and)), which was deleted due to similar reasons. Such a statement should also not be part of the source citation.

Comment: That's now the 2nd time in this comment thread alone that you highlight an incompetent answer of yours on meta. How often did you post that around? Here however, we see indeed the same problem as in that dreadful meta-answer: in commentator's chattily displaying lack of reading comprehension skills and thus invalid complaints about nothing. Contextual hints for references "should also not be part of the source citation"? Fact is: names are not mentioned! Evaluating sources for validity/quality is some kind of taboo for you? Perhaps you should ask a question about that methodological approach?

Comment: @LаngLаngС You are forgetting that mine was not the only answer and there, just as here, you showed your complete distain/disregard of opinions of others that, in any way shape or form, disagrees with yours. Then, of course, there is [Misuse of edit privilege when OP fills answer with inline comments they don't agree to? - History Meta Stack Exchange](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4200/misuse-of-edit-privilege-when-op-fills-answer-with-inline-comments-they-dont-ag). No one agreed with you in both cases that your style is something `what we should aspire`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer deals solely with the topic from where the original **brown shirts** came from.

---

The original supplier of the **brown shirts** to the [Sturmabteilung (SA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturmabteilung) was from the „Sportversand Schill“, which was part of the [Schilljugend](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schilljugend) (Schill Youth) founded in 1923 by [Gerhard Roßbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Ro%C3%9Fbach).

In 1921, Gerhard Roßbach bought up the remaining stock of the East African Lettow shirts, which were brown and was used as a uniform clothing for the cyclists during a bike ride to East Prussia. They were later used for the Salzburg Schill Youth in 1924. They were later taken over for the German Schill Youth by [Edmund Heines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Heines), who in 1925 became responsible for all NSDAP youth groups.

The main source for these statements are convered by the statements made in Gerhard Roßbach 1950 book: *My Way Across The Era: Recollections And Confessions*, quoted below.

---

The (English only) Wikipedia articles use *Toland, John (1976). Adolf Hitler. New York: Doubleday & Company. ISBN 0-385-03724-4* (page 220) as it source. I haven't found the original english text of the source, but based on the german edition of 1977 it is clear that only part of their statement is based on that source.

> **Adolf Hitler / JOHN TOLAND - Page 300, 294 of PDF**
> Die offizielle Uniform der SA war das Braunhemd mit braunem Binder. Die Wahl dieser Farbe war Zufall; eine grosse Lieferung von Hemden, die ursprünglich für die deutschen Kolonialtruppen in Ostafrika bestimmt waren, konnten zu günstigen Grosshandelspreisen erworben werden.
>
> > The official uniform of the SA was the brown shirt with a brown tie. The choice of this color was a coincidence;  A large shipment of shirts, which were originally intended for the German colonial troops in East Africa, could be purchased at low wholesale prices.

---

The first Wikipedia article incorrectly states that Roßbach bought the shirts in Austria in 1924.

> From: [Uniforms and insignia of the Sturmabteilung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniforms_and_insignia_of_the_Sturmabteilung)
> It was Roßbach who effectively invented the "Nazi brownshirt" uniform since, in 1924, Roßbach located a large store of military surplus brown denim shirts in Austria originally intended for tropical uniforms.

This should probably read:

> > It was Roßbach who effectively invented the "Nazi brownshirt" uniform since, during Roßbach's exile in Austria 1924, a large store of military surplus brown denim shirts intended for tropical uniforms in East Africa, which were originally bought in 1921, was taken over by the Schill Youth in Germany.

The second Wikipedia article is not only inprecise but also questionable:

> From: [Sturmabteilung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturmabteilung)
> Brown was chosen as a color for the SA uniform because so many of them were cheaply available after World War I, having originally been ordered during the war for [colonial troops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutztruppe) posted to Germany's former African colonies.

Since most available uniforms (not only in Germany but also in most of it's colonies) were some form of grey.

| Ostafrika | Südwest-Afrika |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

The [Uniforms and insignia of the Sturmabteilung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniforms_and_insignia_of_the_Sturmabteilung) states:

> The most common of these were World War I uniforms with full medals. Also common were uniforms of the Freikorps as well as uniforms of veteran groups such as Der Stahlhelm.

Since the youth groups (which was later intergrated into the SA) allready were using brown, that color was probably selected to distinguish it from the SS (and possibly Mussolini's [Blackshirts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackshirts)).

This should probably read:

> > The official uniform of the SA was the brown shirt with a brown tie. The choice of this color was a coincidence;  A large shipment of shirts, which were originally intended for the German colonial troops in East Africa, was purchased in 1921 by Gerhard Roßbach for use of his own society. They were later used for his Salzburg Schill Youth and in 1924 was taken over by the Schill Youth in Germany. The "Schill Sportversand" then became the main supplier for the SA brown shirts.

---

> **Mein Weg durch die Zeit. Erinnerungen und Bekenntnisse, [Roßbach, Gerhard](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Ro%C3%9Fbach) (1950)**
>
> - **Meine Beziehung zu den Braunhemden**
>   Zum Braunhemd möchte ich bemerken, daß das von mir eingeführte Lettow-Hemd weder in der Farbe noch im Schnitt dem späteren Hitlerhemd gleich war.
>   Im Jahre 1921 hatte ich mit einigen Leuten der Arbeitsgemeinschaft Rossbach eine Radfahrt nach Ostpreußen unternommen. Um für diese Fahrt einheitlich ausgerüstet zu sein, wurde ein Restposten ostafrikanischer Lettow-Hemden, wie sie zuletzt die Offiziere der Schutztruppe getragen hatten, käuflich erworben und an die Radfahrer verteilt. Diese Hemden waren beige-braun, also viel heller als die späteren Hitler-Hemden und mit weißen Perlmuttknöpfen besetzt. Später habe ich diese Hemden als Gemeinschaftskleidung in meiner Organisation und 1924 auch in der Salzburger Schill-Jugend eingeführt. Durch [Edmund Heines](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Heines) wurden sie dann für die SA übernommen und auch vertrieben. Ihre Farbe wurde von Monat zu Monat dunkler. So bin ich zwar der Liquidator des Lettow-Hemdes, nicht aber der Erfinder des "Original"-Braunhemdes gewesen, wie später oft behauptet wurde.
>
> > **My Way Across The Era: Recollections And Confessions, [Roßbach, Gerhard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Ro%C3%9Fbach) (1950)**
> >
> > - **My relationship with the brown shirts**
> >   As to the brown shirts I would like to observe that the Lettow shirt I introduced was neither in color nor in cut the same as the later Hitler shirt.
> >   In 1921 I took part, togeather with others from the Rossbach society, in a bike ride to East Prussia. In order to be uniformly equipped for this trip the remaining stock of the East African Lettow shirts, last used by the officers of the Schutztruppe, were bought and distributed them to the cyclists. These Shirts were beige-brown, so much lighter than the later Hitler shirts and with white mother-of-pearl buttons. Later I introduced these shirts as community clothing in my organization and in 1924 also in the Salzburg Schill Youth. They were then taken over for the SA by [Edmund Heines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Heines) and also distributed. Their color grew darker from month to month.  So I'm the one Liquidator of the Lettow shirt, but not the inventor of the "original" brown shirt as was often claimed later.
>
> <sub>Source of quoted text (in German):</sub>
>
> - [Wie die SA zu den braunen Hemden kam ...oder "urban legends of history"](http://www.reichskolonialamt.de/download/pdf/braune_hemden.pdf)

**Note**: Edmund Heines was responsible for the *Schill Youth* (which became part of the [Hitler Youth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitler_Youth#Origins) in 1926) group, since Roßbach was still in Austrian exil in 1924. Since 1925, he was also responsible for all NSDAP youth groups. This Schill group was the original supplier to the SA with the brown shirts.

> From: [Schilljugend](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schilljugend)
> Einer von Gerhard Roßbachs Gesinnungsgenossen bei der Gründung des Jugendverbandes [Schilljugend](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schilljugend) war der spätere Röhm-Vertraute Edmund Heines. Dieser wurde 1925 von Hitler mit der Zuständigkeit für alle Jugendangelegenheiten der NSDAP betraut. Da der in Österreich weilende Roßbach weiterhin Einreiseverbot für Deutschland hatte, übernahm Heines die Führung der Schilljugend in Deutschland. **Er leitete auch den „Sportversand Schill“, der unter anderem die SA mit Braunhemden versorgte**.
>
> > One of Gerhard Roßbach's comrades in the founding of the [Schilljugend (Schill Youth)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schilljugend) youth association was Edmund Heine's who was later a Röhm-confidante. In 1925 Hitler entrusted him with responsibility for all youth affairs of the NSDAP.  Since Roßbach, who was staying in Austria, was still banned from entering Germany, Heines took over the management of the Schill Youth in Germany. **He also headed the "Schill Sportversand", which among other things supplied the SA with brown shirts**.

---

**Sources:**

- [Wie die SA zu den braunen Hemden kam ...oder "urban legends of history" - Reichskolonialamt](http://www.reichskolonialamt.de/download/pdf/braune_hemden.pdf) (PDF)
- [Adolf Hitler / JOHN TOLAND - (German edition 1977)](https://ulis-buecherecke.ch/pdf_thyssen_krupp_hitler/hitler_und_wie_alles_geschah.pdf)  (PDF)
- [Gerhard Roßbach - Wikipedia (English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Ro%C3%9Fbach)

  - [Gerhard Roßbach - Wikipedia (German)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Ro%C3%9Fbach)
- [Sturmabteilung – Wikipedia (English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturmabteilung)

  - [Sturmabteilung – Wikipedia (German)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturmabteilung#Early_SA_rank_insignia_(1924%E2%80%931929))
- [Schutztruppe – Wikipedia (English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutztruppe)

  - [Schutztruppe – Wikipedia - (German)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schutztruppe)
- [Uniforms and insignia of the Sturmabteilung - Wikipedia (English only)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniforms_and_insignia_of_the_Sturmabteilung)
- [Edmund Heines – Wikipedia (English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Heines)

  - [Edmund Heines – Wikipedia (German)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Heines)
- [Schilljugend – Wikipedia (German only)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schilljugend)

  - [Hitler Youth - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitler_Youth#Origins)
  - [Hitlerjugend – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitlerjugend#Vorl%C3%A4ufer)
- [Blackshirts - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackshirts)

Comment: The most curious aspect of all this is that 'inheritance from colonial troops' over such a stretch of time implies *huge* stockpiles for a miniscule force (blowing up the colonial past as well). / One correction re timeline?: early SS was firmly *within* SA, so grey (& really colourful 'mishmash') is preceeding brown which then in that special case gave way to SS-black? (There is one often shown clip with Himmler as SS subordinate giving his superior a file in office, afair him in Bavarian looking 'Oberland' brown shorts with thick alpine stockings?…)

Comment: @LangLangC As John Toland implies, the color choice was probably a coincidence. In 1921 shirts were needed for the cyclists. The brown ones where available (exactly how many were bought is not meantioned). These were eventually  used in the later Schill Youth groups. The shade of color and style were later changed. It would seem that the SA used the same shirts as the youth groups. Based on existing quotes, I don't think anything more can be determined.

Comment: This goes to the core of the choice of the fashion, but could be better expanded to ridicule in interwar germany.

Comment: @SamuelRussell It is doubful that any reliable, unbiased information will be found about how most peaple felt about the 'fashion' of the day (whether the SA or KPD uniforms). Society then, as now, was relatively split 50:50. Can you find a reliable source for 1960's to today that show whether most peaple `ridicule` the fashion of those periods? Doubtful in my mind. Remember, history has a tendency to repeat itself.